# Оператор OR php не работает

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть код, суть такая: Если мы в группе под номер 5, то не делаем редирект, если под номером 4, тоже не делаем. Почему то работает только на одну группу. Почему то на группу 4 внимания не обращает...

```
if($user_group!=5 or $user_group!=4)
{
  if($technic_user_id!=$user_id)
{
   echo '<script>window.location.replace("../../");</script>';
}
if($technic_id=='')
{
   echo '<script>window.location.replace("../../");</script>';
}
if($user_id=='')
{
   echo '<script>window.location.replace("../../");</script>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос.
Заменил OR, на AND.